# Why tilde (~) doesn't expand when used with CLI argument starting with dash?

Tags: bash, shell, tilde

I lost a couple of hours trying to run VNC server (x0vncserver) and the client refused to connect with weird message that

```
No password configured for VNC Auth
```

The server also prints this error

```
 SVncAuth:    opening password file '~/.vnc/passwd' failed
```

Ok, I wasted a lot of time until I realized  the tilde was neither expanded by the shell, nor by x0vncserver.
Then I ran these tests

```
$ echo --PasswordFile=~/.vnc/passwd
--PasswordFile=~/.vnc/passwd
```

But

```
$ echo PasswordFile=~/.vnc/passwd
PasswordFile=/home/tichomir/.vnc/passwd
```

Why is that? Why the shell refuses to expand tilde if the argument begins with a dash? I thought tilde will always expand as long as it is not quoted, but apparently there is another rule that comes into play?

Comment: Related: [Expansion of tilde in zsh](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/373519)

Comment: See also: [Does ~ always equal $HOME](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a peculiarity of the `bash` shell described in its manual:

> Bash also performs tilde expansion on words satisfying the conditions of variable assignments (as described above under PARAMETERS) when they appear as arguments to simple commands.  Bash does not  do
>          this, except for the declaration commands listed above, when in posix mode.

This means that `bash` *will* expand the tilde in your `PasswordFile=~/.vnc/passwd` string, since it's an argument to `echo` that looks like a variable assignment.

The string `--PasswordFile=~/.vnc/passwd` does not look like a variable assignment since the string `--PasswordFile` is not a valid variable name.

Note that `bash` does not do this when running in POSIX mode, and that other shells, like `zsh`, `ksh` or `yash` do not do this by default (`zsh` has a `magicequalsubst` option for tilde expansion to be performed after unquoted equal signs (`=`) though).

If you want to ensure that the home directory path of the current user is properly expanded as part of an argument to a command, use the `$HOME` value instead of the tilde:

```
echo --PasswordFile="$HOME/.vnc/passwd"
```

---

The "declaration commands listed above" referred to in the manual are the built in commands `alias`, `declare`, `typeset`, `export`, `readonly`, and `local`.

Comment: +1 | I would not think of that.

Comment: Though note: `bash --posix -c '"export" a=~; printf "%s\n" "$a"'` outputs `~`.

Comment: Note that the `~` being expanded in `alias a=~` would be a POSIX conformance bug (and is not useful). But that's how ksh88 did it (that changed in ksh93) and is probably why bash, zsh and pdksh do it as well. Why `yash` which was written against the POSIX spec doesn't do it.

Comment: This is the right answer, but the right _approach_ would have been to just supply the option argument as a separate argument, rather than merged with the option using `=` into one argument.  Then the tilde expansion is at the beginning of a word and the question is moot.

Comment: @JdeBP, as it happens, in the case of `x0vncserver`, `x0vncserver --PasswordFile file` doesn't work, you need `--PasswordFile=file`.

Comment: The argument vector parsing code in that program aims to handle both forms.  I checked.